# Django static file updates on browser

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, web, static

I am currently using django and matplotlib to display charts on the web page.

The way I use matplotlib is I save the chart as a static file in Django then load it in the view templates.

This chart is drawn with the data in the database which gets updated on regular basis.

However, the problem I'm facing is that the chart image won't get updated unless I stop running the Django server, perform collectstatic and re-run the server.

Is there a way to update the static image on the server during runtime?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating a file on a regular basis, then it's *not* a static file. You should look into using a **file storage system** for what you are trying to achieve.

- [Django Docs: Managing Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/)
- [Django Docs: File storage API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/files/storage/)